# Jsoup select excluding Elements with :not, not getting expected text

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to get all text that isn't in a span or in class `_21ok _50f5`, in this case I want to get no text at all, but I keep getting the text.

I tried all combinations of `select(._42ef:not(._21ok._50f5))`, and `select(._42ef).not(._21ok._50f5)` and more , but I still get the text.

```
<div class="_42ef">
 <div class="_6a _5u5j">
  <div class="_6a _6b" style="height:36px"></div>
  <div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
   <div class="">
    <span class="_21ok _50f5">Add your current city</span>
    <span class="img _55ym _55yn _55yo _5tqs _3-9a" aria-label="Loading..." aria-busy="1"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anyone knows what the problem is or how to fix it?

Comment: I tried `div._42ef :not(span)` and it selects all `div` under `_42ef` but it also selects `<div class="">` and the text for that is `Add your current city`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there were several reasons why this was not performing as you had hoped.  Here is an example of some javascript/jquery that works.  I hope it helps:

```
//Look in all elements of your root and specify each filter criteria separately
$('._42ef').find('*').not('span, ._21ok, ._50f5').each(function() {

    //Only get immediate text
    var directText = $(this).clone()
                            .children()
                            .remove()
                            .end()
                            .text().trim();

    //Only add if text has value (and is not just whitespace)
    if (directText) texts.push(directText);
});
```

I also prepared a jsfiddle to help:
https://jsfiddle.net/038o91ec/

Comment: can you do it in java and not javascript?
I see you are using different functions.

Comment: I can have a go with Java - although I've not used it before for this type of function.  I was hoping `$('._42ef').find('*').not('span, ._21ok, ._50f5')` would have helped a little; and the jsfiddle may at least explain why you weren't getting the expected results.